# SwiftUI iOS15 Toolbar's content not refreshing based on the FocusState value

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, combine

I have a view with two `TextFields`. When the first one is focused, I'd like to display `Next` button in the toolbar and when the second text field is focused, I'd like to present `Previous` and `Done` buttons in the toolbar.

I have an `if` statement inside the toolbar, but it looks like it doesn't pick up the change of [`@FocusState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate/) until I type something.

Any ideas how to make it work properly or why doesn't the toolbar pick up the changes?

This is more or less the code (I simplified the actual code):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

enum Field {
    case inLangName
    case outLangName
}


struct MyView: View {
    @FocusState private var focusedTextField: Field?
    @State var inLangName: String = ""
    @State var outLangName: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 15) {
                TextField("In lang name", text: $inLangName)
                    .focused($focusedTextField, equals: .inLangName)
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded { _ in
                        focusedTextField = .inLangName
                    })
                
                TextField("Out lang name", text: $outLangName)
                    .focused($focusedTextField, equals: .outLangName)
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded { _ in
                        focusedTextField = .outLangName
                    })
                
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .onAppear {
                if inLangName.isEmpty {
                    focusedTextField = .inLangName
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    if focusedTextField == .inLangName || focusedTextField == nil {
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            focusedTextField = .outLangName
                        }) {
                            Text("next")
                        }
                    } else if focusedTextField == .outLangName {
                        Button(action: {
                            focusedTextField = .inLangName
                        }) {
                            Text("previous")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            //onDoneButtonClicked()
                        }) {
                            Text("done")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to debug view is refreshed correctly and toolbar has new items, but system keyboard's inputAccessoryView is not refreshed, so it looks like a bug. File to Apple.

Comment: Yeah, I attached `onChange` to print the value of `focusedTextField` and it did change, but the view didn't update. Thanks for the confirmation. Will file to apple.

Comment: Since it is a bug, you can always force the refresh by attaching a `.id()` to the view and changing the `.id()` value in the `.onChange()`. It is a hack, but it is a venerable one from the original SwiftUI and all of its update bugs.

Comment: @Yrb also a good tip, thanks! I decided to have `Previous` and `Next` buttons visible all the time and implement the `Done` button using `.submitLabel` and `onSubmit` on the `TextField`. It is different from what I wanted, but it's fine for now. Bug report has been filed.